# capture exit code from system command in perl

Tags: perl

how can we capture the exit code correctly when we call a command via 'system'?  from the testcase below i consistently capture "-1" which the expectation is "0" for code1 and "1" for code2.

test1.pl

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;

my $code = system("./test2.pl 0");
say "code1  = $code";
system("./test2.pl 0");
say "code1' = $?";

$code = system("./test2.pl 1");
say "code2  = $code";
system("./test2.pl 1");
say "code2' = $?";
```

test2.pl

```
use feature qw(say);

use strict;

say "arg = @ARGV[0]";
my $exit_code = @ARGV[0];
say "this is a dummy script which exit with $exit_code";
exit $exit_code;
```

Output:

```
% ./project_r/test.pl
code1 = -1
code1' = -1
code2 = -1
code2' = -1
```

Comment: % ./project_r/test.pl
code1  = -1
code1' = -1
code2  = -1
code2' = -1

Comment: i am running the perl script in csh

Comment: Re "*i am running the perl script in csh*", Irrelevant. `system` always uses `/bin/sh` (except on Windows), or no shell at all when it can parse the command itself (like in your case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation for [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), `-1` indicates there was a problem trying to execute the command, and that the error message is found in `$!`.

```perl
system(...);
die("Can't run test2: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("test2 killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("test2 exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
say("Child completed successfully.");
```

As you can see by the lack of output of `this is a dummy`, your program never ran.

Likely culprits are:

- The path doesn't refer to an existing file.
- The file isn't executable.

A missing shebang (`#!`) line could render a file non-executable, but I'm presuming you simply left out the shebang lines from your snippets for conciseness (since `./project_r/test.pl` wouldn't run otherwise).

I'm also assuming that the difference in the name of the file you posted (`test1.pl`) and the file you executed (`test.pl`) isn't relevant.

My best guess is that `test2.pl` is in the same directory as `test.pl`/`test1.pl`, which isn't the current directory but a subdircetory of the current directory named `project_r`.

Fix:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

my $code = system("$RealBin/test2.pl", "0");
```

Comment: it is working after i fix the code as you suggested.  just that for the case i expecting it return 1 but i get 256 instead.  any clue on this?

Comment: See the docs for `system` or the first code snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are going to run other Perl programs from a Perl program, you need to use the same settings. Otherwise you might run into situations where you are using a different `perl` with your parent `perl`'s settings:

Your current Perl is in `$^X`:

```
system $^X, 'test2.pl', '0';
```